# Spring Security username is empty when auth with POST but works with PUT and GET

Tags: spring-boot, http, spring-security, postman

**SCENARIO:**
I implemented Basic auth with spring security. I generated a form login and http basic auth. So when I want to send new data, which is a JSON file in my Requestbody, I only works with Put and GEt but not with Post.

**ERROR:**
When I use Post Method ( I'm testing with postman) the username in my `loadUserByUsername(String username)` is always empty. When I do the same call with Get or Put, the username is the way it's meant to be.

**Code:**

I'm not really sure what code parts might be helpful because everything seems to happen behind the scenes. So I hop the SpringSecurityConfic might help

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint);
    http.addFilterAt(new CustomBasicAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManagerBean()), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().failureUrl("/login").successHandler(new RoleBasedAuthenticationSuccessHandler());
    http.logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login").invalidateHttpSession(true).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").permitAll();
}
```

In my SpringSecurotyConfiguration file I have the http.csrf().disable() but still doesn't work.

i there anything I have to take care about when I want to use POST.

Comment: Can you provide the relevant code?

Comment: What is `CustomBasicAuthenticationFilter`? Why don't use the default filter for basic authentication? However, show your request with headers. Do you send a `Authentication` header with username and password BASE64-encoded?

Comment: Yes, I add the auth parameters in the header when I use Post.
CustomBasicAuthenticationFilter is a filter I inserted to differenciate between mobile login and login via browser. This works fine with Get and put. So I don't think it should be the problem.